# CAS SSO building a custom authentication handler

Tags: cas

There are two different groups of people in my workspace.
Those who are regular staff will have their ID beginning with an `s` and followed by a sequence of digits. e.g. `s123456789`.
Those who are non-regular staff will have their ID in all digits. e.g. `81234567`.

Regular staff will be authenticated against LDAP server. Non-regular staff will be authenticated via a RESTful api.

I want to add a service that implements the above strategy.

It will first check if the ID beginning with an `s` if so it then auth using LDAP.
If not, auth using rest api.

After looking up CAS official documentation, I think only custom authentication handler can achieve this.
But how do I get started with cas-overlay-template? Any direction?

Answer (score 0):

To design custom authentication handlers, the overall tasks may be categorized as such:

- Design the authentication handler

```java
public class MyAuthenticationHandler extends AbstractUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler {
}
```

- Register the authentication handler with the CAS authentication engine.

```java
public class MyAuthenticationEventExecutionPlanConfiguration
                    implements AuthenticationEventExecutionPlanConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private CasConfigurationProperties casProperties;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationHandler myAuthenticationHandler() {
        var handler = new MyAuthenticationHandler();
      
        return h;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureAuthenticationExecutionPlan(final AuthenticationEventExecutionPlan plan) {
      plan.registerAuthenticationHandler(myAuthenticationHandler());
    }
}
```

- Tell CAS to recognize the registration record and authentication configuration.

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
   com.example.cas.MyAuthenticationEventExecutionPlanConfiguration
```

See [this link](https://fawnoos.com/2020/10/21/cas62-authn-handlers/) for notes and details.